# undefined behaviour to use raw pointer from a deleted shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr, undefined-behavior, invalid-pointer

I have following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <cassert>

int main()
{
    void* p_any = nullptr;

    {
        auto  p_src = std::make_shared<int>(10); // new instance        
        p_any = p_src.get();                     // get raw unmanaged pointer?
        auto  p_again = reinterpret_cast<int*>(p_any);
        assert(*p_src == *p_again);
    }

    auto  p_again = reinterpret_cast<int*>(p_any); // ??
    std::cout << *p_again <<  "\n";                // undefined?, expected?

}
```

Are the last two statements safe?

I can run it http://cpp.sh/6poh with out put "10",
but is it expected? or just a undefined behavior?

Comment: `assert(*p_src = *p_again);` - are you sure it shouldn't be `==` here?

Comment: fixed typo, thanks

Comment: You can't de-reference pointers to non-existing objects, so no, not safe.

Comment: Yes, it's UB. The pointer has been deleted; dereference on it is UB.

Comment: `cout << '\n'` is a littble bit better than `cout << "\n"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `p_src` object goes out of scope with the closing brace, and since there's no other shared pointer instance the contained pointer will be deleted. So `p_any` will point to deleted data and you will indeed have *undefined behavior*.